# How can I get the PullRequestId via a BuildId?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pull-request, azure-devops-rest-api

How can I get the Pull Request Id via a Build Id? Is there any existing Rest API to support this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the build details with [Builds - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) Rest API (you just need the Build Id):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=5.0
```

In the JSON response, you got also the Pull Request Id:

```
"parameters":"{
      \"system.pullRequest.pullRequestId\":\"1\",\"system.pullRequest.sourceBranch\":\"refs/heads/build\",\"system.pullRequest.targetBranch\":\"refs/heads/master\",\"system.pullRequest.sourceCommitId\":\"2e9f40aee78e1c916a6d6715ce9727d9bfbe940c\",\"system.pullRequest.sourceRepositoryUri\":\"https://shaykia@dev.azure.com/shaykia/Test/_git/Test\"}",
```