# Retrieve pull request ID from a commit

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In my current Azure set up I need to retrieve the pull request id from a build that's triggered from a commit into that branch.

I found this :  [How can I get the PullRequestId via a BuildId?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54901768/how-can-i-get-the-pullrequestid-via-a-buildid) but this is from a pull request, not a commit. If you do a commit the `parameters` object is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A way to do this is by listing all the open pull requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

[Retrieve the build information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

Use the `sourceBranch` from the build to find the `sourceRefName` in the list of pull requests. Then you have the correct pull request and you can use `pullRequestId` to retrieve to pull request id.